# Brakes Pedal on 2004 Pontiac Sunfire Goes to the Floor

Tags: brakes, pontiac, sunfire

Why do my brakes go all the way to the floorboard? I added brake fluid. It's not as bad, but still doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

While there is probably air in the lines (as Mark stated), the bigger question is *why is there air in the lines*. You've either lost some fluid somewhere, or all your brakes are worn out and the calipers have all the fluid in them (effectively draining the master cylinder).  If they are anywhere close to being used up (especially at all four corners), you run the risk of having run your master cylinder dry. Check to see how your brake pads look. Even if the brakes do need changing, you'll need to get your brakes bled. If the brakes aren't at issue, you'll need to discover where the leak is at before you drive it anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Air in system need the bleed the brake lines